# How to select unrelated data in a many-to-many relationship with soft delete?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have data in a many-to-many relationship, where each of our members has can select the subjects that they are studying. This data makes use of a soft-delete pattern, where a DATETIME `archived` field remains `NULL` until such a time that the data is considered deleted.

What we want to do is select subjects that the user is not currently subscribed to, ignoring subjects they are currently subscribed to.

This is the table structure:

```
`member`
- id
- name
- created
- updated
- archived

`subject`
- id
- name
- created
- updated
- archived

`member_subject`
- member_id
- subject_id
- created
- archived
```

The basic query structure we have is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subject.*
FROM subject
LEFT JOIN member_subject ON member_subject.subject_id = subject.id
WHERE subject.archived IS NULL

# Not sure how to go about the rest of the WHERE clause here

ORDER BY subject.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT s.id
FROM subject s
LEFT JOIN member_subject ms
  ON ms.subject_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT(ms.subject_id) = 0
```

...add additional WHERE filter you need.

Answer (score 0):

this will generate all subjects for each user that is currently not being subscribed,

```
SELECT  d.*, e.*
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  a.ID memberID, b.ID SubjectID
            FROM    member a, subject b
        ) c
        INNER JOIN member d
            ON c.memberID = d.ID
        INNER JOIN Subject e
            ON c.SubjectID = e.ID
        LEFT JOIN member_subject f
            ON  c.memberID = f.member_ID AND
                c.SubjectID = f.subject_ID
WHERE   f.member_ID IS NULL
        -- AND d.ID = ''                        -- <<== for specific userID
```